# In React Native, how do you have the keyboard position itself over all the other elements?

Tags: react-native

I've been working on a project, and I have no problem having the keyboard push up other UI elements, but there are a couple screens I just want the keyboard to go straight over the existing layout, and not push anything up. I've been looking for an hour or so, and nothing seems to be doing the trick, and I feel like I'm at the end of my wits.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard should go over your elements if you are not using the KeyboardAvoidingView component

Comment: This should be true for a stock setup.  Makes me wonder if the original OP was using some sort of library (like a navigation package) that embeds things in a KeyboardAvoidingView for them